# How to disable free trial on subscription creation in paypal payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have created a plan that contains 7 day free trial. However in some cases I do not want to provide the free trail, for example any user already tried the free trial offer during previous subscription.
An alternate solution I'm going to implement  two plans, one with a trial and one without. But all subscribed users record under two plans. Are there any way to disable free trial offer when user create subscription? Such as way to override a subscription plan to disable or enable the free trial

Answer (score 0):

Using two plans is the simplest option. You should probably do that.

It is also possible to override an existing `plan_id`'s billing cycles by additionally passing a `plan` object when creating each subscription for approval. See the [create subscription API operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create!path=plan&t=request) for details.

Comment: Preston PHX thanks for your explanation. I'm go with manage two different plans for this case